# getView() never called baseadapter getcount called

Tags: java, android, gridview, baseadapter, getview

I am developing a gridview to display JSON images. I am entering ImageAdapter, but I am not receiving images in the screen indicating that something incorrect occurred while getting the associated view. Is MyArrList null?

I realize that there are other posts similar to my own out there, but I have done deep research into them and cannot find a solution.

Logcat:

```
    V/log﹕ getcount
    08-04 11:02:33.044  22241-22241/com.example.justin.myapplication V/log﹕ getcount
    08-04 11:02:33.060  22241-22241/com.example.justin.myapplication V/log﹕ getcount
    08-04 11:02:33.060  22241-22241/com.example.justin.myapplication V/log﹕ getcount
    08-04 11:02:33.060  22241-22241/com.example.justin.myapplication V/log﹕ getcount
    08-04 11:02:33.060  22241-22241/com.example.justin.myapplication V/log﹕ getcount
    08-04 11:02:33.169  22241-22241/com.example.justin.myapplication V/log﹕ getcount
    08-04 11:02:33.169  22241-22241/com.example.justin.myapplication V/log﹕ getcount
    08-04 11:02:33.177  22241-22241/com.example.justin.myapplication V/log﹕ getcount
    08-04 11:02:33.177  22241-22241/com.example.justin.myapplication V/log﹕ getcount 
            08-04 09:12:44.179    6312-6315/com.example.justin.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 177K, 3% free 8929K/9148K, paused 5ms+2ms, total 37ms
            08-04 09:12:44.179    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 17ms
            08-04 09:12:44.203    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 285K, 6% free 8941K/9452K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
            08-04 09:12:44.289    6312-6315/com.example.justin.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 241K, 3% free 9198K/9464K, paused 1ms+5ms, total 24ms
            08-04 09:12:44.359    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 288K, 5% free 9159K/9612K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
            08-04 09:12:44.359    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 9.093MB for 130826-byte allocation
            08-04 09:12:44.375    6312-6321/com.example.justin.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 85K, 6% free 9202K/9740K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
            08-04 09:12:44.375    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication V/data﹕ {"car_images":[{"CarManufacturerImage":"bmw.png","...}
            08-04 09:12:45.875    6312-6315/com.example.justin.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 269K, 5% free 9299K/9740K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 23ms
            08-04 09:12:46.047    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication V/Bitmap﹕ CarImageLink
            08-04 09:12:46.047    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication V/MyArrList﹕ [{CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b5b7d8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b34d28}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41ba3d10}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b5eb98}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b3c7e8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b9c828}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bb96a0}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b54f48}]
            08-04 09:12:46.054    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication V/return0﹕ [{CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b5b7d8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b34d28}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41ba3d10}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b5eb98}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b3c7e8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b9c828}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bb96a0}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b54f48}]
            08-04 09:12:46.054    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication V/getJSONObject(i)﹕ {"CarManufacturerImage":"bmw.png",....}
            08-04 09:12:46.265    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication V/Bitmap﹕ CarImageLink
            08-04 09:12:46.265    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication V/MyArrList﹕ [{CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b5b7d8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b34d28}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41ba3d10}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b5eb98}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b3c7e8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b9c828}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bb96a0}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b54f48}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b86380}]
            08-04 09:12:46.273    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication V/return0﹕ [{CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b5b7d8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b34d28}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41ba3d10}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b5eb98}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b3c7e8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b9c828}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bb96a0}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b54f48}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b86380}]
            08-04 09:12:46.273    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication V/getJSONObject(i)﹕ {"CarManufacturerImage":"bmw.png",....}
            08-04 09:12:46.468    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication V/Bitmap﹕ CarImageLink
            08-04 09:12:46.468    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication V/MyArrList﹕ [{CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b5b7d8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b34d28}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41ba3d10}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b5eb98}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b3c7e8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b9c828}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bb96a0}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b54f48}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b86380}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b9c420}]
            08-04 09:12:46.468    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication V/return0﹕ [{CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b5b7d8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b34d28}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41ba3d10}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b5eb98}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b3c7e8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b9c828}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bb96a0}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b54f48}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b86380}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b9c420}]
            08-04 09:12:46.476    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication V/getJSONObject(i)﹕ {"CarManufacturerImage":"bmw.png",....}
            08-04 09:12:46.679    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication V/Bitmap﹕ CarImageLink
            08-04 09:12:46.687    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication V/MyArrList﹕ [{CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b5b7d8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b34d28}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41ba3d10}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b5eb98}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b3c7e8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b9c828}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bb96a0}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b54f48}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b86380}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b9c420}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bdedf8}]
            08-04 09:12:46.695    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication V/return0﹕ [{CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b5b7d8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b34d28}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41ba3d10}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b5eb98}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b3c7e8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b9c828}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bb96a0}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b54f48}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b86380}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b9c420}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bdedf8}]
            08-04 09:12:46.695    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication V/getJSONObject(i)﹕ {"CarManufacturerImage":"bmw.png",....}
            08-04 09:12:46.711    6312-6315/com.example.justin.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 315K, 4% free 9420K/9812K, paused 7ms+2ms, total 31ms
            08-04 09:12:46.906    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication V/Bitmap﹕ CarImageLink
            08-04 09:12:46.906    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication V/MyArrList﹕ [{CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b5b7d8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b34d28}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41ba3d10}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b5eb98}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b3c7e8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b9c828}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bb96a0}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b54f48}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b86380}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b9c420}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bdedf8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b50150}]
            08-04 09:12:46.914    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication V/return0﹕ [{CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b5b7d8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b34d28}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41ba3d10}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b5eb98}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b3c7e8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b9c828}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bb96a0}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b54f48}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b86380}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b9c420}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bdedf8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b50150}]
            08-04 09:12:46.914    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication V/getJSONObject(i)﹕ {"CarManufacturerImage":"bmw.png",....}
            08-04 09:12:47.117    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication V/Bitmap﹕ CarImageLink
            08-04 09:12:47.117    6312-6352/com.example.justin.myapplication V/MyArrList﹕ [{CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b5b7d8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b34d28}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41ba3d10}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b5eb98}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b3c7e8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b9c828}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bb96a0}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b54f48}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b86380}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b9c420}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bdedf8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b50150}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41baa090}]
    08-04 11:02:37.255  22241-22279/com.example.justin.myapplication V/return0﹕ [{CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b86600}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b34e38}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41ba3c28}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b59b68}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b0b0f8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b9bee0}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bb94a8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b54d10}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b37458}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b411b8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bdec58}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b4ff18}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bc37c8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bcfbd8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41c05140}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b19c30}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bf4ce0}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bcf7a0}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b4b120}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b2d638}]
08-04 11:34:59.794    4563-4563/com.example.justin.myapplication V/return3﹕ [{CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41ace870}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b35768}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41ba4298}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b72cd0}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b3d2e8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b842e8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bb99c0}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b642e8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41ad6a60}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b8b8c0}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bdf338}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b5f4f0}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bc3608}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41ba9308}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41be9138}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b4bcb0}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bab378}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bb0408}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b5a6f8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bec410}]
08-04 11:34:59.794    4563-4563/com.example.justin.myapplication V/value﹕ value
08-04 11:34:59.794    4563-4563/com.example.justin.myapplication V/value1﹕ value1
08-04 11:34:59.794    4563-4563/com.example.justin.myapplication V/log﹕ getcount
08-04 11:34:59.794    4563-4563/com.example.justin.myapplication V/log﹕ getcount
08-04 11:34:59.794    4563-4563/com.example.justin.myapplication V/return2﹕ com.example.justin.myapplication.JSONImageViewer$ImageAdapter@41afd290
08-04 11:34:59.794    4563-4563/com.example.justin.myapplication V/return2.1﹕ [{CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41ace870}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b35768}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41ba4298}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b72cd0}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b3d2e8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b842e8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bb99c0}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b642e8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41ad6a60}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b8b8c0}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bdf338}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b5f4f0}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bc3608}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41ba9308}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41be9138}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b4bcb0}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bab378}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bb0408}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41b5a6f8}, {CarImageLink=android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@41bec410}]
08-04 11:34:59.810    4563-4563/com.example.justin.myapplication V/log﹕ getcount
08-04 11:34:59.810    4563-4563/com.example.justin.myapplication V/v﹕ convertView inflating
08-04 11:34:59.810    4563-4563/com.example.justin.myapplication V/convertview﹕ android.widget.RelativeLayout{41baedb8 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
08-04 11:34:59.810    4563-4563/com.example.justin.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-04 11:34:59.810    4563-4563/com.example.justin.myapplication W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41266930)
08-04 11:34:59.825    4563-4563/com.example.justin.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.justin.myapplication.JSONImageViewer$ImageAdapter.getView(JSONImageViewer.java:238)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
            at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1040)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-04 11:34:59.856    4563-4567/com.example.justin.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 650K, 8% free 9424K/10140K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 32ms
```

Activity_column.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ColPhoto"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any suggestions/insight as to why I cannot receive images through getView() yet can get values for getCount() are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what is the logcat output?

Comment: @OlegOsipenko There are no errors to output, sir.

Comment: I know, but as you logs various methods it is good to look at resulting sequence of Log calls

Comment: @OlegOsipenko I updated with the logcat. For data integrity purposes, I omitted some array information. Also, the logcat was too long to post here fully so here is some of it. Thanks.

Comment: @OlegOsipenko return 3 in the logcat also has the value [] btw.

Comment: remove publishProgress() in the end of onPostExecute()

Comment: @OlegOsipenko For clarification, move publishProgress() to the end of onPostExecute() or remove publishProgress() from the end of doInBackground()?

Comment: And why do you create new MyArrList inside doInBackground()? that's the reason I believe why you get empty list in onPostExecute - you're adding items in the local variable inside this method

Comment: @OlegOsipenko I am new to Android development and Java. I am still learning and took code from a tutorial. So, I must create and add items to MyArrList not in doInBakground() form what I am understanding. Where do I create and add items then?

Comment: just remove the line `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();` from `doInBackground()`

Comment: @OlegOsipenko I made those changes and now the logcat shows that the view began inflating so convertview was null and I received an nullpointerexception at           ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ColPhoto);. I will post the updated logcat and xml. Why are both the if(convert==null) and outside statements being passed through since both are logged?

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I forgot to change `v` in this line to `convertView`. And as `v` not initialized you're getting NPE. I think if you do this change it should work

Comment: @OlegOsipenko That is quite alright, sir. Would I also change return v to return convertView?

Comment: certainly, you have to change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onCreate()` method change `getApplicationContext()` to `this` in the line where you're creating adapter and remove `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

And remove MyArrList duplicate from `doInBackground()`
Try to change your task as follows:

```
class LoadContentFromServer extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Object> {

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {

        String url = "http://..no looking..";

        JSONObject data;
        try {

            data = new JSONObject(getJSONUrl(url));
            Log.v("data", data.toString());
            JSONArray dataArray = data.getJSONArray("car_images");

                /*
                 * TotalRows = Show for total rows
                 * TotalPage = Show for total page
                 */

            int displayPerPage = 9;   // Per Page
            int TotalRows = data.length();
            int indexRowStart = ((displayPerPage * currentPage) - displayPerPage);

            if (TotalRows <= displayPerPage) {
                TotalPage = 1;
            } else if ((TotalRows % displayPerPage) == 0) {
                TotalPage = (TotalRows / displayPerPage);
            } else {
                TotalPage = (TotalRows / displayPerPage) + 1;
                TotalPage = (int) TotalPage;
            }
            int indexRowEnd = displayPerPage * currentPage;
            if (indexRowEnd > TotalRows) {
                indexRowEnd = TotalRows;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
                //HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                JSONObject c = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.v("getJSONObject(i)", dataArray.getJSONObject(i).toString());

                // Thumbnail Get ImageBitmap To Object
                HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmap(c.getString(TAG_IMG));
                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
                map.put(TAG_IMG, d);
                Log.v("Bitmap", TAG_IMG);

                MyArrList.add(map);
                Log.v("MyArrList", MyArrList.toString());
                Log.v("return0", MyArrList.toString());
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {

        Log.v("return3", MyArrList.toString());
        // Disabled Button Next
        if(currentPage >= TotalPage) {
            btnNext.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else {
            btnNext.setEnabled(true);
        }

        // Disabled Button Previous
        if(currentPage <= 1) {
            btnPre.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else {
            btnPre.setEnabled(true);
        }
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        imageAdapter.addAll(MyArrList);
        imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.v("return2", imageAdapter.toString());
        Log.v("return2.1", MyArrList.toString());
    }
}
```

and adapter:

```
class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> array;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        array = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.v("log", "getcount");
        return array.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return array.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public void addAll(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list) {
        array.clear();
        array.addAll(list);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        //If convertView is null create a new view, else use convert view
        if(convertView==null) {
            Log.v("v", "convertView inflating");
            convertView = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate
                    (R.layout.activity_column, null);
        }

        Log.v("convertview", convertView.toString());
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColPhoto);
        iv.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) array.get(position).get(TAG_IMG));
        iv.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);

        return v;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am receiving a blank screen still and return2.1 in the logcat is []. I will post the updated code and logcat.

Comment: Log.v("v", "convertView inflating"); and  Log.v("convertview", convertView.toString()); are not in the logcat so I can assume that getView() was never called. However, getCount() was called since logcat shows output...

Comment: With some logging, it is obvious to me that the addAll method is indeed call properly so I am not understanding why return 2.1 (so MyArrList) would still be empty.

Comment: Thank you for all of your time, help and expertise. I greatly appreciate it, sir.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call

```
protected String onPostExecute()
{
    // change your data set here then call
    imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}
```

in onPostExecute() not in OnProgressUpdated() also you must call it when after you have modified the data set

EDIT
onProgressUpdate is normally for updating the ui (ie an progress bar). it will get called every time you call

```
 protected String doInBackground()
 {
    // other code ommited
    String progress = "test";
    publishProgress(progress);
 }
```

which you are not doing hence it will never update the data set.

try moving your code from the OnProgressUpdated to onPostExecute();

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your response. So OnProgressUpdate does not need to exist? Also can you please explain what you mean when you say "you must call it when you have modified the data set"? Are you referring to the fact that notifyDataSetChanged must be called in onPostExecute() since the values of the data set are changed by then?

Comment: onProgressUpdate() takes integer parameter and this integer is progress value. It is optional method in AsyncTask. It is better to add received items in onPostExecute(). In order to update view when data source is changed you have to call notifyDatasetChanged()

Comment: @OlegOsipenko So, I can remove onProgressUpdate() all together? Also, perhaps you could explain what Mark meant by "you must call it when you have modified the data set"...is he referring to the fact that notifyDataSetChanged must be called in onPostExecute() since the values of the data set are changed by then?

Comment: He meant that when you add or delete items you need to call notifyDataSetChanged in order to make ListView update it's view with new content

Comment: OnProgressUpdate is designed to help you show progress of your task execution. If you don't update progress it is not mandatory  to use it

Comment: @OlegOsipenko Ok. I removed OnProgressUpdate to simplify things. So, after   MyArrList.add(map);, I must call notifyDataSetChanged even though that will be called later in OnPostExecute()?

Comment: No, you can call it onPostExecute()

Comment: @OlegOsipenko Ok. Please look at my update. When I do what you see above, I still receive a blank screen.. Log cat corresponding to the block: V/return2﹕ com.example.justin.myapplication.JSONImageViewer$ImageAdapter@41b03b58
08-04 09:38:08.765  17537-17537/com.example.justin.myapplication V/return2.1﹕ []

Comment: @OlegOsipenko It appears that update() in AdapterHelper which is in OnPostExecute was never called and it appears that MyArrList values are not recognized after doInBackground. Any suggestions are appreciated, sir.

Comment: @OlegOsipenko Ok. Thank you. Hope to hear from you soon. In the meantime, I realized that I never called update when I created new AdapterHelper() in OnPostExecute(). I am having a difficult time getting the parameters right for something like: new AdapterHelper().update(...something).